# Alternative to Lotka Volterra

Tags: growth

Would you guys know any kind of differential equations that would dictate population growth without relying on Lotka Volterra ? Thanks ^^

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because equations for population growth are not biology.

Comment: I think this question could use some improvement and background to make sure it's clear what the goals are; right now it seems overly broad. However, I disagree strongly that discussing equations that are highly relevant to biology is not biology, unless that discussion is not directed at a biologically relevant problem.